# What is the best way to handle Nginx rewrite with subdomains?

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I need to parse out a subdomain and add it to end of the url, for example:

`subdomain.mysite.com` needs to rewrite to `subdomain.mysite.com/subdomain`

`subdomain.mysite.com/login` needs to rewrite to `subdomain.mysite.com/subdomain/login`

Trouble arises because I have a set of reserve words that I don't want to match, for example the various different environments.

`dev-web.mywebsite.com` should not map to `mywebsite.com/dev-web`

This is what I have so far... am struggling with the nginx syntax and regex in general.

```
if ($host ~ ^([^.]+)\.(.+)) {
    set $subdomain $1;
}

if ($subdomain ~* ^(dev-web|uat-web)$) {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/$subdomain$request_uri permanent;
}
```

The various errors I get are too many redirects or it is just not redirecting at all.
`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`
`subdomain.mysite.com/subdomain/subdomain/subdomain/subdomain...`

Comment: Have you considered using multiple `server` blocks? Perhaps one regular expression block to capture the *subdomain*. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names).